# Calculate If Number String Loops | Hex Grid Round World

Tags: javascript, html, 2d, game-engine

So I have a hex grid that has a 100x100 grid...  The Grid is recursive so when you scroll left past the '0,0' position it draws the '99,0' row etc...  My issue is finding an algorithm that will let me calculate if I am looping back around...

Example:
96 - 97 - 98 - 99 - 0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4

Both of these have starting locations less then the ending location
If I was at row 2 and the screen panned to row 98:

2 to 98  WORKS (98) - 100 = -2  then -2-(2)  = distance of 4

96 to 98  FAILS (98) - 100 = -2  then -2-(96) = distance of 98 (correct is 2)

Both of these have ending locations less then the starting location
However this doesn't work both directions... so we do this...
from row 98 to row 2:

98 to  2  WORKS (2) + 100 = 102 then 102-(98) = distance of 4

96 to 98  FAILS (96) + 100 = 196 then 196-(98) = distance of 98 (correct is 2)

As you can see I cant just say if start < end or start > end as the number loop screws that up.  I need to detect when "Crossing the line" some how...

---

After Jonathan suggestions I realized that the client display and behind the scenes didn't have to line up.  I have changed the engine so there are 2 hex values...  one is the actual position like 98,2 0,0 2,1.  The other is a literal position from the view port.

Looks like this:

```
 Actual:  96  97  98  99  00  01  02  03  04  <= display in client & reference hexGridModel

 Literal: -4  -3  -2  -1  00  01  02  03  04  <= use to calculate buffer position updates from camera
```

The literal is just from the "display" standpoint.  I will need a fix later to see if we go passed -100 or +100 but this solved issue for now and map sizes are dynamic so will need later work on that

Now I just used this for any case.

```
    var x, y = 0
    x = this.buffer.coords.current.x - this.buffer.coords.last.x;
    y = this.buffer.coords.current.y - this.buffer.coords.last.y;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's not really possible without more information than you've given us.  Take the example of moving from 2 to 98.  You will not be able to tell whether the user moved from `2 -> 1 -> 0 -> 99 -> 98` or `2 -> 3 -> 4 -> ... -> 97 -> 98`.

So the key to being able to determine this is knowing the *direction* in which the player or object is moving.

If you know that, you can say (assuming 0 is at the left boundary of the grid and 99 is at the right boundary of the grid):

```
if ((direction == LEFT && new_pos > old_pos) || (direction == RIGHT && new_pos < old_pos) {
    // The "line" has been crossed.
} else {
    // The "line" was not crossed.
}
```

If you also need to know the distance travelled, you can break it down like this:

```
GRID_SIZE = 100
if (direction == LEFT && new_pos > old_pos) {
    distance = (GRID_SIZE - new_pos) + old_pos;
} else if (direction == RIGHT && new_pos < old_pos) {
    distance = (GRID_SIZE - old_pos) + new_pos;
} else {
    distance = abs(new_pos - old_pos)
}
```

Comment: yes... this was another idea but the problem is the camera for the game copies data from a buffer to display.  so whats visible on the screen is camera.position + camera.pan.  So while actively panning calculating the true direction seems hard.  if they move 100 pixels left then goes right 50pixels in the same "pan".  I would need to add an indicator as the mouse.click.position would not be reliable...

Comment: I guess the best thing would be each time the "drag" event is fired while you pan.  I have to check your current mouse coordinate against the last time it fired (milliseconds ago) and determine a direction...  seems this is the best way?

Comment: You could do that.  You can also try to determine where the edges of the grid are, in comparison to the edges of the viewport.  If the left edge of the grid is greater than the left edge of the viewport, then the "line" has been crossed.  Similarly, if the right edge of the grid is less than the right edge of the viewport, then the "line" has been crossed.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I posted the following before I saw the update to the question. It's what I guessed you might have meant in your original question. Maybe it'll still be helpful somehow.*

I don't really understand the requirement as worded, so I'm guessing that it is "Find the shortest distance between two positions, allowing wrapping across the 99/0 boundary if it is shorter".

This function returns an object with three properties, the distance, the direction, and wrapAround (true/false). And I threw in a `toString()` for ease of testing it out.

```
function shortestDistance(startPosition, endPosition) {
   var difference = startPosition > endPosition
                  ? startPosition - endPosition
                  : endPosition - startPosition,
       wrapped = difference > 50;


   return {
      distance      : wrapped ? 100 - difference : difference,
      direction     : (startPosition < endPosition
                      ? (wrapped ? "left" : "right")
                      : (wrapped ? "right" : "left")),
      wrappedAround : wrapped,
      toString      : function() {
                         return (
                             this.distance === 0
                             ? "Didn't move"
                             : "Travelled " + this.distance 
                               + " to the " + this.direction + ", and "
                               + (this.wrappedAround ? "did" : "didn't")
                               + " wrap around.");
                      }
   };
}

var result = shortestDistance(2,98);
alert(result.distance);      // 4
alert(result.direction);     // "left"
alert(result.wrappedAround); // true

alert(shortestDistance(2,98));
  // Travelled 4 to the left, and did wrap around.
alert(shortestDistance(98,2));
  // Travelled 4 to the right, and did wrap around.
alert(shortestDistance(96,98));
  // Travelled 2 to the right, and didn't wrap around.
alert(shortestDistance(98,96));
  // Travelled 2 to the left, and didn't wrap around.
alert(shortestDistance(43, 43));
  // Didn't move
alert(shortestDistance(1, 50));
  // Travelled 49 to the right, and didn't wrap around.
alert(shortestDistance(1, 51));
  // Travelled 50 to the right, and didn't wrap around.
alert(shortestDistance(1, 52));
  // Travelled 49 to the left, and did wrap around.
alert(shortestDistance(50, 1));
  // Travelled 49 to the left, and didn't wrap around.
alert(shortestDistance(51, 1));
  // Travelled 50 to the left, and didn't wrap around.
alert(shortestDistance(52, 1));
  // Travelled 49 to the right, and did wrap around.
```